# JNI issue while passing a string to android code

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface

we are facing an issue while passing string from JNI .c code to android. Given below the codes

.c code

```
char* getSignatureMd5(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)

{`char * sign = loadSignature(env, obj);`




    MD5_CTX context = { 0 };
    MD5Init(&context);
    MD5Update(&context, (unsigned char*)sign, strlen(sign));
    unsigned char dest[16] = { 0 };
    MD5Final(dest, &context);

    int i;
    static char destination[32]={0};
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            sprintf(destination, "%s%02x", destination, dest[i]);
    }

    return destination;
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_sign_signaturecapturesbi_MainActivity_getToken(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,
                                                                    jstring string) {
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "MyApp", "inside getToken");
char *signValue = getSignatureMd5(env, obj);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "MyApp", "inside ExceptionCheck if %s", signValue);
 char* msg = signValue;


jstring result;

 puts(msg);


__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "MyApp", "msg %s", msg);


result = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,msg);
 return result;
}
```

Android native code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   mJavaText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.java_sign);
  mJniText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jni_sign);
   // mJavaText.setText("Get token from jni:" + getPackage());
    //mJniText.setText("Get token from jni:" + getToken());
    try {

        String tokenvalue =  getSignature();
        System.out.println("tokenpackage in android ffi "+ tokenvalue);
       mJniText.setText("Get token from jni:" + tokenvalue);
        // mJniText.setText("Get token from jni:" + getPackage);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // This will catch any exception, because they are all descended from Exception
        System.out.println("Error in android ffi "+ e.getMessage());

    }

}



static {
    System.loadLibrary("check-sign");

}
public native String getToken(String str);
public native String getPackage();
```

public String getSignature(){
        //mJavaText.setText("Get token from jni:" + getPackage());

```
    String valuetoken =  getToken("hello");


System.out.println("valuepackage in android ffi "+ valuetoken);
    // mJniText.setText("Get token from jni:" + getToken());
    return valuetoken;

    }

    }
```

But here i am getting below error

JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewStringUTF called with pending exception 'java.lang.NullPointerException' thrown in unknown throw location

Please help me to get it resolev this issue

I have tried with below code. still I am getting Null pointer exception

```
jstring Java_com_sign_signaturecapturesbi_MainActivity_getToken(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "MyApp", "inside signature");
   char *signValue = (char*)malloc(50);
   strcpy(signValue, getSignatureMd5(env, obj));
   jstring result = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, signValue);
   __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "MyApp", "result if %s", result);
   return result;
}
```

Added loadSignature method & jstringTostring method

```
char* loadSignature(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)


{
 jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/content/ContextWrapper");
 //this.getPackageManager();
 jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "getPackageManager",
         "()Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;");
 if (mid == NULL) {
     return "";
 }
 jobject pm = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, obj, mid);
 if (pm == NULL) {
     return "";
 }

 //this.getPackageName();
 mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "getPackageName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
 if (mid == NULL) {
     return "";
 }

 jstring packageName = (jstring)(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, obj, mid);

 // packageManager->getPackageInfo(packageName, GET_SIGNATURES);
 cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, pm);
 mid  = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "getPackageInfo", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/content/pm/PackageInfo;");

 jobject packageInfo = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, pm, mid, packageName, 0x40); //GET_SIGNATURES = 64;

 cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, packageInfo);
 jfieldID fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, cls, "signatures", "[Landroid/content/pm/Signature;");
 jobjectArray signatures = (jobjectArray)(*env)->GetObjectField(env, packageInfo, fid);
 jobject sign = (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, signatures, 0);

 cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, sign);
 mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "toCharsString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
 if(mid == NULL){
     return "";
 }

 jstring signString = (jstring)(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, sign, mid);

 return jstringTostring(env, signString);
 }
```

---

```
char* jstringTostring(JNIEnv* env, jstring jstr)


{
 char* rtn = NULL;


jclass clsstring = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String");
 jstring strencode = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "utf-8");
 jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clsstring, "getBytes", "(Ljava/lang/String;)[B");
 jbyteArray barr= (jbyteArray)(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, jstr, mid, strencode);
 jsize alen = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, barr);
 jbyte* ba = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, barr, JNI_FALSE);
 if (alen > 0)
 {
     rtn = (char*)malloc(alen + 1);
     memcpy(rtn, ba, alen);
     rtn[alen] = 0;
 }
 (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, barr, ba, 0);
 return rtn;


}
```

Comment: I am getting value till "__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "MyApp", "msg %s", msg);" if i ma not worng when i try to pass it using NewStringUTF. i am getting the null pointer exception. is it because of the declaration issue ?

Comment: Where is `loadSignature`?

Comment: i have edited the post with all methods

Comment: Ok, so one of those JNI calls in `loadSignature` probably throws a `NullPointerException`. Use `ExceptionCheck` to check for exceptions after any JNI call that could throw an exception. And don't use any return values as inputs to other JNI functions without making sure that they're valid first.